# How to set an AAPT flag in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I am using Eclipse for Android development, instead of Android Studio. (I have my reasons; I can't use AS at the moment.)

Now I need to use `VectorDrawableCompat` at the moment. As mentioned in [the section titled "First things first" here,](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.fm7qfdasd) we have to turn on an AAPT flag in order to use `VectorDrawableCompat`. Now in [the post](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#9028), the method mentioned is for Gradle (i.e. Android Studio):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

**My question is that how do I set this AAPT flag in Eclipse?**